# Array of generic type as argument to function

Tags: arrays, swift, generics

This is a very simple problem to explain, but it's driving me nuts!

I have a generic `Event` class:

```
class Event<T> {
    // Etc...
}
```

On that class I want to add a class function that takes an array of `Event`s and returns another generic type (`EventListener`):

```
public class func listenAny<V>(listener: AnyObject, events: [Event<V>]) -> EventListener<V> {
    // Etc...
}
```

For some reason, this code doesn't compile!

```
let e1 = Event<Int>()
let e2 = Event<Int>()

class Listener {}
let l = Listener()

Event.listenAny(l, events: [e1, e2])
```

The compiler throws an error on the last line:

[image: error]

Here's a piece of code that you can paste on a Playground (I tested this on a Playground on Xcode 6.1.1) and experience the frustration for yourself:

```
public class Event<T> {
    private var eventListeners = [EventListener<T>]()

    public class func listenAny<V>(listener: AnyObject, events: [Event<V>]) -> EventListener<V> {
        let eventListener = EventListener<V>(listener: listener)
        for event in events { event.addListener(eventListener) }
        return eventListener
    }

    private func addListener(listener: EventListener<T>) -> EventListener<T> {
        eventListeners.append(listener)
        return listener
    }
}

public class EventListener<T> {
    weak public var listener: AnyObject?
    private init(listener: AnyObject) {
        self.listener = listener
    }
}



let e1 = Event<Int>()
let e2 = Event<Int>()

class Listener {}
let l = Listener()

let v = [e1, e2]
Event.listenAny(l, events: v)
```

Why is this not working?

PS: I intend for the array of events to be a variadic parameter. I hope that if I get this to work with an array, I can do the same with a variadic parameter.

PSS: It seems that if I make the `listenAny` a global function, it works. It might be a problem with the type system (T from Event in conjunction with V from the function...)

Comment: It seems to me that the type parameter `<V>` in `listenAny` is not really needed. Why don't you drop that (and replace `V` by `T` in the method)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to supply the generic type of the class Event. The following code compiles correctly:

```
Event<Int>.listenAny(l, events: v)
```

Note: I use Int as the generic type, but you can use any type.